# Angular 5 - TypeError: Array.from is not a function

Tags: angular

Hello I'm trying to debug Angular 5 app build for production. Now I'm running build artifacts including sourcemaps and I'm building the angular app with command

`build --prod --env=prod --build-optimizer --sourcemaps`

than I have stack like this logged into appinsights

```
            TypeError: this._results.find is not a function
    at e.find (https://gilitickets.azureedge.net/bookingapp-live/20180503.2/main.8ea73b7f474a1fff0865.bundle.js:1:70596)
    at n._syncDescribedByIds (https://gilitickets.azureedge.net/bookingapp-live/20180503.2/main.8ea73b7f474a1fff0865.bundle.js:1:1318967)
    at n._next (https://gilitickets.azureedge.net/bookingapp-live/20180503.2/main.8ea73b7f474a1fff0865.bundle.js:1:1316635)
    at n.__tryOrSetError (https://gilitickets.azureedge.net/bookingapp-live/20180503.2/main.8ea73b7f474a1fff0865.bundle.js:1:36100)
    at n.next (https://gilitickets.azureedge.net/bookingapp-live/20180503.2/main.8ea73b7f474a1fff0865.bundle.js:1:35211)
    at n._next (https://gilitickets.azureedge.net/bookingapp-live/20180503.2/main.8ea73b7f474a1fff0865.bundle.js:1:34345)
    at n.next (https://gilitickets.azureedge.net/bookingapp-live/20180503.2/main.8ea73b7f474a1fff0865.bundle.js:1:34016)
    at n.notifyNext (https://gilitickets.azureedge.net/bookingapp-live/20180503.2/main.8ea73b7f474a1fff0865.bundle.js:1:39157)
    at n._next (https://gilitickets.azureedge.net/bookingapp-live/20180503.2/main.8ea73b7f474a1fff0865.bundle.js:1:36623)
    at n.next (https://gilitickets.azureedge.net/bookingapp-live/20180503.2/main.8ea73b7f474a1fff0865.bundle.js:1:34016)
```

and thanks to the npm package `sourcemapped-stacktrace`

I can retrace it back to

```
    TypeError: Array.from is not a function
    at find (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:6336:29)
    at find (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/form-field.es5.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:607:39)
    at _syncDescribedByIds (webpack:///node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/form-field.es5.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:400:18)
    at call (webpack:///node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:249:15)
    at __tryOrSetError (webpack:///node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:189:26)
    at next (webpack:///node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:128:25)
    at _next (webpack:///node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:92:17)
    at next (webpack:///node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:151:29)
    at notifyNext (webpack:///node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/InnerSubscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:25:20)
    at _next (webpack:///node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.pre-build-optimizer.js:92:17)
```

and this is the part I don't understand. How come build optimizer can throw exceptions during normal run in the browser. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing? Or why I see stacktrace from webpack and not my code?

Comment: post your source code

Comment: @Sajeetharan I don't think that's possible as its a whole app

Comment: wherever you are using  array.find

Comment: in 16 results in 8 files.

Comment: Run the app in dev mode and reproduce the error. You'll be able to see the exact place where it's originating from. To me it looks like you're trying to call find on something that is not an array.

Comment: I would very much like to do that, but I have no idea how this happened as its from production from real user, moreover it was run on the device which I don't have. During testing I fixed all bugs I could find, obviously.